# How to enable native flags with AOSP mm command

Tags: android, build, android-source

I am current building on AOSP and to build a module is use 'mm' command.  However, I would like to enable some  build flags with this command.  The .mk file has defined some native flags already. For example, without building in android system, to enable debugging i would do: make NDK_DEBUG=1 -j8.  However, I am blocked on how to insert this flag with 'mm'.
I have this flag defined in my .mk

ifeq ($(DISK_REST),1)

$(info Disk Size Restriction Is On)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDISKCACHE_TRIMMING_ENABLED

endif

So I would like to enabled this flag with mm command.  I tried 'mm DISK_REST=1'. 
But that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass LOCAL_CFLAGS to mm if the Android.mk in the current directory is not overriding it. If it does, your only option is editing Android.mk.

Can you try mm like this?

DISK_REST=1 mm